# Bootstrap lide side group item

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4, side-menu

I have this bootstrap side menu and codeigniter code , but I want to add a sub menu or drop down. I tried other solution but no avail, the drop down and sub menu won't response when clicked. I wish you could help me.
P.s. I only found this and modify a bit.

```
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="side-menu">
    <div>
        <ul class="list-side-menu">
            <?php
                $location = $this->uri->segment(1);
            ?>
            <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'home' || $location === 'item') {echo 'active-link';}?> ">

                <a class="<?php if ($location === 'home') {echo 'active-text';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("home") ?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><br>Order</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'home' || $location === 'item') {echo 'active-link';}?> ">

                <a class="<?php if ($location === 'home') {echo 'active-text';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("home") ?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span><br>PRODUCTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'new_item') {echo 'active-link';}?> ">
                <a class="<?php if ($location === 'new_item') {echo 'active-link';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("new_item") ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>ADD PRODUCT</a>
            </li>
<!--            <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'sales') {echo 'active-link';}?>">
                <a class="<?php if ($location === 'sales') {echo 'active-link';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("daily_sales_report") ?>"><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span><br>Sales</a>
            </li>-->
            <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'categories') {echo 'active-link';}?> "><a class="<?php if ($location === 'categories') {echo 'active-link';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("categories") ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span><br>Categories</a></li>
                    <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'home' || $location === 'item') {echo 'active-link';}?> ">

                <a class="<?php if ($location === 'customer') {echo 'active-text';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("customer") ?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-user"></span><br>Customer</a>
            </li>
                        <?php
        if ($this->session->userdata('account_type') == 'Admin') {
            ?>
        <li class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 'accounts') 
       {echo 'active-link';}?> ">
            <a class="<?php if ($location === 'accounts') {echo 'active-
       link';}?>" href="<?php echo base_url("accounts") ?>">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-
          user"></span><br>USER'S ACCOUNTS</a>
        </li>
        <?php
        }
         ?>
        <li id="log-out" class="list-side-group-item <?php if ($location === 
                 'logout') {echo 'active-link';}?> "><a href="<?php echo 
         base_url("logout/out") ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon 
                  glyphicon-log-out"></span><br>Logout</a></li>

            </ul>
</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Seems like code for Bootstrap **3**... What version are you using? Have you included all JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0):

```
      <li class="dropdown">
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                           <li><a href="#1.html">pagename</a></li>
                  </ul>
       </li>

      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
       <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
           <li><a href="#">Components Dropdowns</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```